# JavaFX saving extended class variables

Tags: javafx

In my evergrowing app I have a BaseClass with around 50 variables. There are 10 other classes which extend from the BaseClass. The reason is that these 10 classes have many variables in common, but also some exclusive to the class itself. Now I'm trying to save each extended class, so I have to combine the BaseClass variables with the ClassX variables. Here is a picture:

[image]

I can do this with something like this in each ClassX:

```
super.saveData();
saveLocalData();
```

That means I only have to provide a single saveData in the BaseClass, BUT many repeats of saveLocalData() - 10 in fact.

In each class I can get a list of the variables simply with:

```
Field[] vars = DisplayField.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

and I can write the variable names and values like this:

```
bw.write(f.getName() + "=" + f.get(this) + "\n");
```

I can do the same for all the ClassX classes and build up a text file like that.

Then it struck me that if I can get to the BaseClass for each ClassX from the FileIOClass, I can just have one single saveData() (consisting of two parts). I can get as far as:

```
for (DisplayField field : fieldList) // Iterate all the CLassX's
field.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("saveDisplayField").invoke(bw);
```

And then I got horribly stuck. Can anyone 'unstick' me OR am I just barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: What type of variables are these? If you need to save e. g. a list, you can go horribly wrong with that. There's not enough information about your requirement. From the looks of it I'd rather use an annotation framework like e. g. [JAXB](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/12/jaxb-tutorial-xml-binding.html) to save the data.

Comment: The variables are all basic types e.g. double, int, boolean etc. Where I need to store things like dropshadow parameters, I store the 'settings' only, not the DropShadow class - again only basic types. So nothing tricky to store. But regardless of the type of variables, the basic problem/question remains.

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting yourself and making your application not extensible by thinking you'd only need basic types (for now).

There are various solutions to your problem. You could e. g. use [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html) for saving a hierarchical data structure, it already comes with Java.

Here's a quick example:

BaseClass.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    Class1.class,
    Class2.class
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Base")
public class BaseClass {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "var1", required = true)
    protected int var1;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "var2", required = true)
    protected int var2;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "var3", required = true)
    protected int var3;

    public String toString() {
        return "var1=" + var1 + ", " + "var2=" + var2 + ", " + "var3=" + var3;
    }
}
```

Class1.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Class1")
public class Class1 extends BaseClass {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "varX", required = false)
    protected int varX;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "varY", required = false)
    protected int varY;

    public String toString() {
        return "var1=" + var1 + ", " + "var2=" + var2 + ", " + "var3=" + var3 + ", varX=" + varX + ", varY=" + varY;
    }

}
```

Class2.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Class2")
public class Class2 extends BaseClass {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "varA", required = false)
    protected int varA;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "varB", required = false)
    protected int varB;

    public String toString() {
        return "var1=" + var1 + ", " + "var2=" + var2 + ", " + "var3=" + var3 + ", varA=" + varA + ", varB=" + varB;
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class XmlExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // marshal base
        BaseClass base = new BaseClass();
        base.var1=1;
        base.var2=2;
        base.var3=3;

        String baseXml = marshal( base);

        // marshal class1
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.var1=1;
        class1.var2=2;
        class1.var3=3;
        class1.varX=10;
        class1.varY=20;

        String class1Xml = marshal( class1);

        // marshal class2
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        class2.var1=1;
        class2.var2=2;
        class2.var3=3;
        class2.varA=40;
        class2.varB=50;

        String class2Xml = marshal( class2);

        // unmarshal base
        unmarshal(baseXml);

        // unmarshal class1
        unmarshal(class1Xml);

        // unmarshal class2
        unmarshal(class2Xml);

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static String marshal( BaseClass base) {

        try {

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BaseClass.class);

            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(base, stringWriter);
            String xml = stringWriter.toString();

            System.out.println("XML:\n" + xml);

            return xml;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e);
        }

    }

    public static void unmarshal( String xml) {

        try {

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BaseClass.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);

            Object clazz = (Object) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(stringReader);

            // create/cast here whatever class you need
            if( clazz.getClass().isAssignableFrom( BaseClass.class)) {
                System.out.println( "BaseClass:");
            }
            else if( clazz.getClass().isAssignableFrom( Class1.class)) {
                System.out.println( "Class1:");
            }
            else if( clazz.getClass().isAssignableFrom( Class2.class)) {
                System.out.println( "Class2:");
            }

            System.out.println( clazz + "\n");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e);
        }

    }
}
```

console output:

```
XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Base var1="1" var2="2" var3="3"/>

XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Class1 varX="10" varY="20" var1="1" var2="2" var3="3"/>

XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Class2 varA="40" varB="50" var1="1" var2="2" var3="3"/>

BaseClass:
var1=1, var2=2, var3=3

Class1:
var1=1, var2=2, var3=3, varX=10, varY=20

Class2:
var1=1, var2=2, var3=3, varA=40, varB=50
```

You can serialize any kinds of objects with this very conveniently, even lists and formatting requiring objects like date objects.

And even if you don't intend to do it this way, I'd never use reflection for that kind of requirement. Rather implement some kind of "serializeToFile" interface in each class.

Comment: Wow, that's a whole new world to me. So give me a couple of hours (days?) to digest all this and as they say "I'll keep you posted" ;-)

Comment: And thank you for such exhaustive examples. It's one of the things I appreciate about StackOverflow - how people go out of their way to help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my first answer, here's another of the various solutions, one which uses reflection (as you want), since this was your question. But as I said in the other answer, you're limiting yourself by this.

I'd create a custom annotation, so that you can still do whatever you prefer in the beans.

The annotation: Persist.java

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD})  
public @interface Persist {
}
```

BaseClass.java

```
public class BaseClass {

    @Persist
    Integer var1;

    @Persist
    Integer var2;

    @Persist
    Integer var3;

}
```

Class1.java

```
public class Class1 extends BaseClass {

    @Persist
    Integer varX;

    @Persist
    Integer varY;

}
```

Class2.java

```
public class Class2 extends BaseClass {

    @Persist
    Integer varA;

    @Persist
    Integer varB;

}
```

And this is how you could use the classes and serialize their values:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class MainApp {

    public static void log(BaseClass base) {

        System.out.println( "\nClass: " + base.getClass().getName());

        Class parent = base.getClass().getSuperclass();
        while( parent != null) {
            logFields( base, parent);
            parent = parent.getSuperclass();
        }

        logFields( base, base.getClass());
    }

    public static void logFields(BaseClass obj, Class clazz) {

        try {

            for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {

                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Persist.class)) {

                    Annotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(Persist.class);
                    Persist test = (Persist) annotation;

                    System.out.println(field.getName() + " = " + field.get(obj));

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BaseClass base = new BaseClass();
        base.var1 = 1;
        base.var2 = 2;
        base.var3 = 3;
        log(base);

        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.var1 = 4;
        class1.var2 = 5;
        class1.var3 = 6;
        class1.varX = 10;
        class1.varY = 20;
        log(class1);

        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        class2.var1 = 7;
        class2.var2 = 8;
        class2.var3 = 9;
        class2.varA = 30;
        class2.varB = 40;
        log(class2);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Class: BaseClass
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = 3

Class: Class1
var1 = 4
var2 = 5
var3 = 6
varX = 10
varY = 20

Class: Class2
var1 = 7
var2 = 8
var3 = 9
varA = 30
varB = 40
```

And then you serialize the data to a file in whatever class you prefer.